# Any reason why my Python code is not showing up?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am learning how to code in Python and using the IDLE, I have put in this code, however when I hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, nothing happens... no output occurs.

Is this due to maybe the fact that the code I have put in doesn't need an output? Or maybe I am saving it wrongly. Would love to know the reason as it is slightly upsetting.

```
X = "X"   #This is to indicate one piece of the game 
O = "O"   #this is to indicate another piece of the game
EMPTY = "" # an empty square on the board.
TIE = "TIE"  #represents a tie game 
NUM_SQUARES = "9" #number of squares on the board

def display_instruct(): #this is a function with the name display_instruct.
    """display game instructions."""
    print \
          """ Welcome to the greatest challenge of all time: Tic-tac toe. This would be a showdown betweene your human brain
and my silcon processor You will mkae your move known by entering a number 

                     0 | 1 | 2
                     ---------
                     3 | 4 | 5
                     ---------
                     6 | 7 |8

        Prepare yourself, human. The ultimate battle is about to begin. \n """

def ask_yes__no(question): 
    """Ask a yes or no question"""
    response = None
    while response not in ("y", "n"):
        response = raw_input(question).lower()
    return response

#this produces a function. It receives a question and thenn responds with an answer which is either yes or not

def ask_number(question, low, high):
    """Ask for a number within the range"""
    response = None
    while response not in range(low, high):
        response - int(raw_input(question))
    return response
    #remember that when defining the functions, you have to put in colons. The user recieves a question and then has to give an answer.

def pieces():
     """Determine if player or computer goes first""" #docstrings are used to name the functions.
    go_first = ask_yes_no("Do you requre the first move?y/n: ")
    if go_first == "y":                        #important to have two equal signs because you are giving a variable a name. Notice that one function callled another.
        print "\n Then take the first move, you will need it."
        human = X
        computer = 0
    else:
        print "\n Your bravery will beyour undoing .... I will go first."
        computer = X
        human = O
    return computer, human
```

Comment: You're not *running* anything. You defined a bunch of constants and functions, but you don't call them. Did you mean to call a function? (Also, your indentation is busted.)

Comment: I've seen this code before...is this is the Tic-Tac-Toe game from chapter 6 of the book _Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner_?

Comment: Hey guys, yes indeed it's the Tic Tac Toe game. Did you use it?

Comment: @user2357112 I Aaah okay then, I know the indentation is all over the place here, the whole spaces rule when placing something on here, threw me off a bit. So I should expect any output then? I was just confused that although I had included raw_input into my code, not a single thing came up

Comment: All you done is define several functions and some global data. Additional code will have to be added that calls them and uses it.

Comment: Aaah okay, thanks for that. Incidentally, how did you start learning python? Which books did you read, which specific resources did you use. Seems like such an enjoyable language and would like to be fluent in it

Comment: "Learn Python the Hard Way".. (seriously!)

Comment: Thank you! I heard about it sometime ago and I am going to use it from now

Comment: @TKA - I thought it was that program.  I was going to say to read the rest of the chapter.  It tells you how to launch the program and see some results.  Also, I learned Python from the same book.  [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) is also a very good resource.  So is [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_overview.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You need to define and call a main function

```
def main():
   display_instruct()
   #the rest of the code


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The reason your code doesn't run is because what you have is function definitions

`def func() ...`

and value assignments

`x=5`

To actually run something you will either need to define a main function that takes all the things you have defined and combines them in a meaningful way or append to the bottom of the code something similar to what you would write in the main function.